# French citizenship through an uncle

Tags: french-citizens

My father's uncle was born in Damascus and served in the French army, dying for France in 1915 at Souchez, France.

Does this help me in any way with the acquisition of French citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. If your father's uncle would have become French (and that's already a big if), there are complex rules regarding his own children and whether they would still be French living abroad but in your case none of that is relevant, as he is not your ascendant.